# JavaScript/Webcal - Protocol detection?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, icalendar, webcal

I'm getting ready to release an iCal subscription feature, and I'd like to set the protocol to `https://` or `webcal://`, depending on browser support. I'm aware that webcal is an unofficial protocol, but is there a way I can check if the browser supports it? So far nothing seems to make it work in IE8, and I'm about to test IE9+, but I'd prefer to offer graceful degradation for all browsers that don't understand `webcal://` (as I understand it, the Android browser also appears to have issues with it).